# Updating state with props on React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app, where props from a parent component are passed to a child component and the props then set the state on the child.

After I send an updated value to the parent component, the child component isn't updating the state with the updated props.

How do I get it to update the state on the child component?

My pared-down code:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: ''} 
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({name: this.props.data.name});
    }
    handleUpdate (updatedName) {
        this.setState({name: updatedName});
    }
    render () {
        return <Child name={this.state.name} onUpdate={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)} />
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: ''} 
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        this.setState({name: this.props.name});
    }
    handleChange (e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }
    handleUpdate () {
        // ajax call that updates database with updated name and then on success calls onUpdate(updatedName)
    }
    render () {
        console.log(this.props.name); // after update, this logs the updated name
        console.log(this.state.name); // after update, this logs the initial name until I refresh the brower
        return <div>    
                    {this.state.name}
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    <input type="button" value="Update Name" onClick={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)} />
                </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to implement [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) in your child:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({name: newProps.name});
}
```

**Edit:** `componentWillReceiveProps` is now deprecated and will be removed, but there are alternative suggestions in the docs link above.

Comment: You know those times you just want to say "I love you" to a random SO poster, well this is one of those times. Thank you kind person.

Comment: Was looking for this all day! Trying to update state to child, and this did it

Comment: It's already 2018, I don't know if it would be good to update this answer according the react official docs. [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) will be deprecated in the future and they recommend to use something like [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) instead.

Comment: Thanks, added a note to that effect.

Answer (score 8):

Calling `setState()` in [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) doesn't cause additional re-render. Receiving props is one render and this.setState would be another render if that were executed within a method like [componentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate). I would recommend doing the `this.state.name !== nextProps.name` in [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) so it's always checked for any update.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({name: nextProps.name});
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.state.name !== nextProps.name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would also be good to check if you even need to update the state, since this will cause a re-render.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if (this.state.name !== newProps.name) {
    this.setState({name: newProps.name});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things. The way you bind the functions on click is unusual to say the least. I would suggest that you either do it on constructor, or use an arrow function instead (this will bind the function to the class automatically).

```
export default class Parent extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {name: ''} 
    }

    handleUpdate = (updatedName) => {
        this.setState({name: updatedName})
    }

    render () {
        return <Child name={this.state.name} onUpdate={this} />
    }
}

export default class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ name: this.props.name });
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }

  handleUpdate() {
    // ajax call that updates database with updated name and then on success calls onUpdate(updatedName)
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.name); // after update, this logs the updated name
    console.log(this.state.name); // after update, this logs the initial name until I refresh the brower
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.name}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Update Name"
          onClick={this.handleUpdate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I would suggest you to decide whether the props need to be **managed/updated from Parent or Child**. Should Parent be responsible for handling state, then you should propagate the handleUpdate to the Parent:

```
//@Parent component
<Child handleUpdate={()=> this.handleUpdate} .../>
```

```
//@Child component
handleUpdate = () => {
   this.props.handleUpdate
}
```

You shouldn't be required to use any other function (in React 16+) for managing props from child to parent and vice versa.

Usually these "bidirectional" cases are structure "smells" and signify that the *separation of concerns* for each component has been misadjusted  or has not been fully figured out yet.