# Updating component's state using props with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state of my component using props that I get from the parent component, but I get the following error message:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I want the local state to update if the prop changes.
The similar posts ([Updating component's state using props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967007/updating-components-state-using-props), [Updating state with props on React child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154967/updating-state-with-props-on-react-child-component), [Updating component's state using props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967007/updating-components-state-using-props)) did not fixed it for me.

```
import React, {useState} from "react"


const HomeWorld = (props) => {
    const [planetData, setPlanetData] = useState([]);
    if(props.Selected === true){
        setPlanetData(props.Planet)
        console.log(planetData)
    }


    return(
        <h1>hi i am your starship, type: {planetData}</h1>
    )
}

export default HomeWorld
```

Comment: Why are you trying to update state with props, though?  Why not just render `props.Planet` instead of `planetData`?

Comment: @Retsam I would ask the same question, but as you can see in the other questions that he mentions, I think he really wants to have the prop in the state.

Comment: I have got same idea with Retsam.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to run it only once.

```
import { useEffect }  from 'react'

... 

const HomeWorld = (props) => {
    const [planetData, setPlanetData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.Selected === true){
            setPlanetData(props.Planet)
            console.log(planetData)
        }
    }, [props.Selected, props.Planet, setPlanetData]) // This will only run when one of those variables change

    return(
        <h1>hi i am your starship, type: {planetData}</h1>
    )
}
```

Please notice that if `props.Selected` or  `props.Planet` change, it will re run the effect.

## Why Do I Get This Error ?

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

What is happening here is that when your component renders, it runs everything in the function, calling `setPlanetData` wich will rerender the component, calling everything inside the function again (`setPlanetData` again) and making a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're generally better off not updating your state with props.  It generally makes the component hard to reason about and can often lead to unexpected states and stale data.  Instead, I would consider something like:

```js
const HomeWorld = (props) => {
    const planetData = props.Selected
        ? props.Planet
        //... what to display when its not selected, perhaps:
        : props.PreviousPlanet

    return(
        <h1>hi i am your starship, type: {planetData}</h1>
    )
}
```

This might require a bit more logic in the parent component, to control what displays when the Selected prop is false, but it's a lot more idiomatic React.